How to tell Windows to use LAN and WLAN simultaneously to increase speed?
I have a 1Gbit/s connection to my ISP, but my home network has an old Ethernet cable(from the router to PC) which can only transfer 100Mbit/s. I also have a Wifi adapter which has approx. a transfer rate of 200-300Mbit/s.
I'm using Windows 11 on this PC.
Normally the LAN connection is sufficient, but for heavy downloads like Steam library I would like to speed it up by combining both network adapters.
I tried various solutions I could find on the internet, eg. bridging, deactivating priority, setting a Windows policy(I don't remember which). Nothing of it worked, for example, if I create a bridge of them, Windows still uses only the Ethernet adapter, and the speed is capped at 100Mbit/s.

Using both won’t increase speed. You would need a load balancer to actually use two internet connections at once. Your Ethernet connection stick at 100MB/sec suggests a cable problem. That connection at minimum would be 1000 MB/sec (10/100/1000 Ethernet card). Just replace the cable. What you want is not possible, load balancing WiFi and Ethernet, won’t achieve what you want. That’s only for two service providers, allowing a single Ethernet cable, to your networking gear

@Ramhound the second network adapter is wireless and has a higher throughput.

What you want isn’t possible on Windows. What is possible is creating a local Steam cache. You’ll still be limited by the improper Ethernet cable.

What you need is called internet bonding. However, as answered above, you need 2 internet connections that can be combined.

If you troubleshoot your 100Mbps Ethernet link, you can probably get it running 1Gbps quite easily. Easier than setting up some kind of link aggregation / bonding / load-balancing.

If you have gigabit internet, the router supplied by your ISP should have gigabit ports, if your pc also has a gigabit NIC and the physical cable is the bottleneck, get a new cable?

Note that the bandwidth values of wireless and wired adapters are not comparable. The bandwidth values of a Wifi adapter printed on it's packaging are theoretical values you will never get in reality (and the air is a shared media used by multiple devices), where as a 1GBit Ethernet adapter will always reach that value (unless you have a defect cable or something like that).

@NickSlash the cable is in the house walls.
